# Windows 11: Extremely slow file transfer to CFexpress card via Thunderbolt 4 USB-C

Tags: windows, usb, windows-11, usb-c, card-reader

## Problem Description

My Windows 11-based laptop is driving me nuts. I am trying to copy over to a CFexpress card about 8'500 photo files (JPEG). The average file size is around 13.87Mb.

When I start the copy process, it goes very fast for a few seconds. I can see transfer speeds of ~700Mb/s reported. But after 5-7 seconds the speed falls down sharp to levels of less than 20Mb/s. It almost feels like either some kind of queue is being exhausted, or an app or OS "decides" to slow down the process:

[image]

The laptop is connected to AC power during the entire file transfer process. I made sure to install all the OS updates and software updates offered by HP Assistant.

I have NOT updated any USB drivers yet, however. Maybe this is something I should do.

By the way, could that be a defender or antivirus software messing with the copy process?

## Hardware used

| top speed | device | type | declared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 Gbps | Sony MRW-G2 | CFexpress Type A/SD card reader | SuperSpeed USB 10Gbps(USB 3.2 Gen 2) |
| 40 Gbps | HP ZBook Power G8 Mobile Workstation | laptop | 1 Thunderbolt™ 4 with USB4 Type-C® 40Gbps signaling rate (USB Power Delivery, DisplayPort™ 1.4) |
| 10 Gbps | USB 3.2 10Gb/s | cable (primary) |  |
| 40 Gbps | Thunderbolt 4 | cable (alternative) |  |

## Question

Obviously, 20Mb/s is way below the 10 Gb/s which is the lowest of the speeds of the hardware I use.

**How do I bring the copy speed closer to 10 Gb/s?**

## Update 1: Task Manager screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Explorer or the CMD *copy* for many small files is slow, because they copy one file at a time and then add it to the filesystem. Try another utility, such as Windows [Robocopy (*Robust File Copy*)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

The arguments for *Robocopy* are manifold. For example, try these:

- **/MT[:n]**  Creates multi-threaded copies with n threads. n must be an integer between 1 and 128.
- **/z**  Copies files in restartable mode. In restartable mode, should a file copy be interrupted, Robocopy can pick up where it left off rather than re-copying the entire file.
- **/r:[n]**  Specifies the number of retries on failed copies. The default value of n is 1,000,000 (one million retries). [Pick a lower number, e.g., 20 or 100, rather than 10<sup>6</sup> to speed things up. This increases the risk of a *barely* salvageable file being lost, but not greatly.]
- **/w:[n]**  Specifies the wait time between retries, in seconds. The default value of n is 30 (wait time 30 seconds). [So, one bad file, retried 10<sup>6</sup> times, with 30 seconds between, i.e., the defaults, would delay finishing ~1 year (well, a year is closer to 32*10<sup>6</sup> seconds).]
- **/v**  Produces verbose output, and shows all skipped files. [If you are worried that any files were lost because of **/r** and **/w**.]

Comment: Thank you for advice. I wasn't aware of that tool. Unfortunately for me, the behavior observed is extremely similar, with no improvement whatsoever. Only about 500-550 files were copied quickly, under 15-25 seconds. Then, the copy process got super slow again. Same write speed of 20 Mbps is reported by the Task Manager for the disk D: (picture attached to UPD1).